# Connection reset exception in the simplest client-server

Tags: java, sockets

I'm a newbie in Java network programming and my question may seem too obviously, but suppose I've a client

```
package com.client.main;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(r.readLine());
    }
}
```

and server:

```
package com.server.main;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Socket client = server.accept();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
        writer.write("Hello from server");
    }
}
```

I was running the server and after whole server's code has been executed, the client throws an exception without printing any message. Ther is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at com.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Could you explain that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> after whole server's code has been executed

Simple. Your server is done executing so it shut down and the client got a connection reset by peer.

Try putting your server code in an infinite loop so it does not shut down too fast before you appreciate the magic of sockets. Like this,

```
while(true){
    // Your code here
    try{
        Thread.sleep(10); // Don't forget this!
    } catch(InterruptedException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code explanation: Putting your code in an infinite loop keeps your server program alive. Remember that Java code executes more or less linearly*. The `Thread.sleep` is necessary because otherwise your server will hog resources; think of it as your CPU's "breathing time".

Now, to terminate your server, send it a shutdown signal (like `kill` or Ctrl+C).

*Once you take into account the things the JVM does behind your back, it is not really linear. It is important to note this fact when doing Sockets because Sockets might eventually lead to Threads, and the things the JVM does is important when you handle concurrency. **But for the purposes of a simple client-server program, I think this little handwaving is permissible.**

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work too. What's happening is client program just waiting after executing of `System.out.println(r.readLine());` and after the server has been shut down the same exception is thrown.

Comment: Could you update your code? I don't understand how the client program will "wait" after the `println`. After that, it is supposed to terminate. It may throw Exceptions but, nonetheless, it is supposed to terminate and not hang around waiting.

Comment: Change `writer.write("Hello from server");` to `writer.write("Hello from server\n");`. Your client is waiting for a whole line (defined as a string of text with a new line at the end) and your server is only sending a string of text, but no new line to tell the client the line has ended.